# WPF APP won't be running after publishing from Visual Studio but would be running with administrator

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, publish

I am ready to publish my WPF APP. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and everything works well when debugging. Since the App will only be used for some research data collection I didn't plan to publish on web. The approach I adopted was publishing wizard to my local machine from the project property on Visual Studio.

After publishing, there were several files in the published folder: a setup file, a file with my app name, a file called autorun, a folder called application files. If I double click set up file, there would be a short installation process and an icon of my app appearing in start menu. However, the app could not be open by clicking that icon. The weird thing was: if I right click set up file, and "run as administrator" the app will lanuch automatically after the short process of installation and worked well as it in Visual Studio. But when I tried to search from start menu, it turned out the App was not installed at all. That means, the App could not be open and running by right clicking the set up file and "run as administrator"! This is not what I want, does anyone has any cue?

I also tried many solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241885/wpf-clickonce-installs-but-nothing-happens) but no one helps.

Comment: FWIW I would use a more mature installer tech then the impossible to configure one that comes with "Publish". You will almost certainly see better results.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Hi Thanks for your response! Any mature tools or technique that you can recommend? Sorry it's my first time developing WPF app..

Comment: Wix is free, but complicated. You might try Software Reccommendations SE.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Does Software Recommendation SE stand for Software Recommendation Stack Exchange? Sorry I didn't really get it.. is there tools for publish/deploy WPF APP?

Comment: Yes, that site accepts recommendation requests like this. And yes, tools like Wix build proper installers for programs including WPF appliscations

Comment: Why don't  you just use the files in ./bin/Debug or ./bin/Release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your help. I finally found the problem. It was because I tried to set a value in register table in order to get the App automatically launch with the system start up. There was neither error nor warning when running on Visual Studio. However, it didn't work after publishing.

So what I did was remove the code of setting value in register table and I also figured out another way to launch it with the system start up.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your anti-virus software is blocking the installation process.

I had many users with the same installation problem when they had installed bitdefender on their system.

Give it a try and deactivate your anti-virsu software.